# LyX not accessing styles, classes, and bibliographies

Tags: lyx

Precursor info:  I'm on a Mac operating OSX 10.9.4, which I updated to months ago, before this problem started. I'm running LyX 2.1.

Just a few days ago I was using LyX with no problems. The next day, error messages started popping up such as:

> "The selected document class  Article (Standard Class) requires
>   external files that are not available. The document class can still be
>   used, but the document cannot be compiled until the following
>   prerequisites are installed:  article.cls"

and

> "The module linguistics requires a package that  is not available in
>   your LaTeX installation, or a converter that you have not installed.
>   LaTeX ouptut may not be possible. Missing prerequisites:
>     covington.sty"

and

> "The module natbib requires a package that  is not available in your
>   LaTeX installation, or a converter that you have not installed. LaTeX
>   ouptut may not be possible. Missing prerequisites:    natbib.sty"

I also cannot access any of my .bib documents. When I go to Tools > TeX Information, nothing is there (i.e. the LaTeX classes and styles, and BibTeX styles and databases sections are all empty).

I do, however, have what I believe is the correct directory available:

username/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/.bib_docs_here
username/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/.bst_docs_here
username/Library/texmf/tex/latex/packages_&_styles_here

Things I've tried:

- Tools > Reconfigure, then quitting and restarting LyX.
- I was on LyX 2.0 when this started. I erased LyX 2.0 from my computer
  and installed LyX 2.1. At Library/Application Support/LyX-2.1/ there
  is the same texmf file there, so it does look like the installation
  of LyX 2.1 correctly copied all of that information.
- Full computer restart.
- Removing and replacing all TeX related folders in Library.

I'd very much appreciate any diagnoses of what the problem might be and/or advice on how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Please try backing up your LyX home folder (find its location in Help > About) and then removing it. Do that *without* LyX running. Then start LyX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is what resolved it for me:

1. reinstall latest version MacTeX at: https://tug.org/mactex/
2. install latest version of LyX: 2.1.1. (see: http://www.lyx.org/Download)
3. Tools --> Reconfigure.
4. Restart, check: Document --> Settings --> Document Classes: these should now be available.

I see from your question that you had already done most of these steps, so I am not sure if this will help you. Although, if you have had no success until now then following the exact steps (in this order) may be worth a try.

Comment: That did the trick. I had already downloaded LyX 2.1.1. So just installing the latest MacTeX version and reconfiguring worked fine. Many thanks!

Comment: Same for me, I updated MikTex (since I'm running Windows) but then forgot to do LyX Reconfigure. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what resolved it for me:

1. reinstall latest version [BasicTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) via [homebrew](http://brew.sh)
2. Tools --> Reconfigure.
3. Restart, check: Document --> Settings --> Document Classes: these should now be available.

If you still miss files, you can use tlmgr to install missing packages. For a good documentation on this and other things, have a look at alexandersavi.nl/blog/latex-on-mac-os-x/.