# MiKTeX209-jpeg.dll is missing

Tags: miktex, windows, updating

After installing MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7,  I can open TeXworks but only if I do not use the MiKTeX updater. After updating MiKTeX after installation and whenever I try to open TeXworks, I get the error message "... MiKTeX209-jpeg.dll is missing". I have reinstalled several times but have not been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: The dll is in my miktex in the package miktex-jpeg-bib-2.9. Check (with the package manager (admin) if it is installed.

Comment: The package miktex-jpeg-bib-2.9 is installed

Answer (score 4):

See bug at Miktex sourceforge:

[Sourceforge Issue Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2546/)

Solutions are given by the bug opener in link.

Comment: Also see https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2545/

Comment: I installed `miktex-jpeg-bin` from the package manager and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you just installed LyX and Miktex for the first time on your computer (as I did on a brand new computer), you can just Synchronize Miktex (to update packages list), then do an Update, this will fix the missing DLL issues.

Then you have to reconfigure LyX (LyX > Tools > Reconfigure) in order [to refresh the document templates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197730/lyx-not-accessing-styles-classes-and-bibliographies) (else you will get a "missing article.cls" error).

Answer (score 3):

Open the miktex package manager in admin mode (should be available from start menu programs). Install all uninstalled packages in the category `\Miktex X.X executables (windows-x86)`. That should (hopefully) fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is also happened to me when I installed TexStudio and updated the Miktex. But the problem is fixed after I opened the MiKTex Package Manager (Admin) then installed manually `miktex-jpeg-bin-2.9` and `miktex-latex`. Maybe your problem can be solved by the same ways too.