# Recently Installed Protext, but MiKTeX209-jpeg.dll is missing

Tags: protext

This is what I have done:

1) Downloaded ProTeXt-3.1.7-061016.exe  22-Jun-2016 16:48   2.2G      http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/systems/windows/protext/

2) Installed MikTex on C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9

2.1) Executed miktex-update_admin in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\internal

3) Downloaded the last version of TexStudio and installed it on C:\Program Files\TeXstudio

And when I want to run it, it shows that message.

What I have tried:

Installing the same version that is contained in Protex, Tried installing it in program files (x86), googling the problem but not finding anything that helped me (or at least that I understood as help). I have already checked [MiKTeX209-jpeg.dll is missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345900/miktex209-jpeg-dll-is-missing) but I don't see how that thread could be of help to me (maybe I am not understanding something). And also installing and re-installing many times.

I am really lost here, please help!

Comment: 1) Don't mix `Program Files` and `Program Files(x86)` installations if you don't want to have a mess. 2) This file is part of `miktex-jpeg-bin-2.9` for the 32 bits version, or `miktex-jpeg-bin-x64-2.9` for the 64 bits version. Try uninstall and reinstall it with MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: Hi, Bernard. Thanks for your answer. I started messing with the installations since it alone installed them on different parts: miktex on prgram files, and texstudio on x86. Where should I install them then? On the program files and not (x86)?

Comment: I think it should be left where the installer proposes. What I meant is you should not install two different versions of MiKTeX. Personally, I use a dedicated partition and have no problem.

Comment: I used the versions proposed in the locations proposed and I had the problems originally

Comment: Did you check whether miktex-jpeg-bin(-x64)-2.9 is installed, and does contain the missing .dll?

Comment: How do I check that? I think I do not understand what does that mean: is it a folder somewhere? :( Oh, no I see. I will check it in the manager and then I check here thanks!

Comment: You check it with MiKTeX Package Manager: it makes a list of all packages, and has a column ‘Installed on`.  If it's not installed, the corresponding item in the column is empty.

Comment: I have just re-installed Miktek, checked the manager and when I right clicked the package it showed the option to install it. 

miktek-jpeg-bin-x64-2.9

Category: miktek 2.9 executables (windows-64)

Then I installed TexStudio from Protext launcher... and the problem continues :(

This is not my first time installing LaTex with ProTex, but it is my first time doing it on windows 10...

Comment: When I try to use the update wizard on MikTexPackage Manager (Admin) it says: MikTex Encountered an internal error... with no information. And when I press copy info I get nothing. :(

Comment: I don't understand why you constantly install a miktex with protext when obviously the miktex in protext is broken. While it is normally possible to correct such a broken installation with a sensible use of synchronization, installations of missing packages and updates it is certainly easier to simply use the standard miktex net installer. Btw: unless you need a multiuser installation I would suggest to install miktex in single user mode "only for you" in your normal user account and some folder where you have write access, e.g in C:\miktex. Much easier to manage.

Comment: It is not obvious that it is broken, not at least for beginners in LaTeX or simply casual users.

What I did finally was just downloading separately from their websites both MikTek and TexStudio and everything is working fine. 

Will I be missing something from Protex?

Comment: Well a dll was missing and it didn't work. I call this "obviously broken".  I never saw any reason to use protext so I don't know if something will be missing but I'm rather certain that you can install everything that you want separately as you did with texstudio.

Comment: Yep, that was what I did, though ProText is supposed to be noob-friendly with stuff or something. I just followed the recommendations on latex-project site.

Anyways, mystery wasn't solved, but at least it is not a problem anyore